# Too many values to unpack with python CSV reader and Geopy

Tags: python, csv, geopy

```
import csv
from geopy import geocoders

g = geocoders.Google()

spamReader = csv.reader(open('locations.csv', 'rb'), delimiter='\t', quotechar='|')

for row in spamReader:
    a = ', '.join(row)
    #print a
    place, (lat, lng) = g.geocode(a, exactly_one=False)
    print "%s: %.5f, %.5f" % (place, lat, lng)
```

The data inside locations.csv looks like:

```
6943     Australia
6944     Australia
6945     Australia
6946     Australia
6947     Australia
6951     Australia
```

For some reason I am left with a "too many values to unpack" error. The values do print out if I use the commented print statement. Does anyone know why this would be happening?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is the `exactly_one` argument to `g.geocode`. When I run this in the shell I get:

```
 >>> g.geocode('6943, Australia', exactly_one=False)
 [(u'Australia 6943, Villafontana, Tijuana Municipality, Baja California, Mexico',
  (32.4988788, -116.8620506)),
 (u'Australia 6943, Castelar, Buenos Aires Province, Argentina',
  (-34.7036339, -58.6423071)),
 (u'Australia 6943, Rosario, Santa Fe Province, Argentina',
  (-32.9913482, -60.6398934)),
 (u'Australia, Lebanon', (33.8879118, 35.4749439)),
 (u'Australia, Juliaca, Peru', (-15.4897806, -70.146677)),
 (u'Australia, Lima District 15007, Peru', (-12.0397296, -76.9944836)),
 (u'Australia, Manila, Philippines', (14.48538, 121.0394822)),
 (u'Australia, Conchal\xed, Santiago Metropolitan Region, Chile',
  (-33.3929606, -70.6780826)),
 (u'Australia, Chiguayante, Biob\xedo Region, Chile',
  (-36.9556346, -73.0145556)),
 (u'Australia, Copiap\xf3, Atacama Region, Chile', (-27.3978776, -70.2934656))]
```

Now, you're trying to break up that big list into just `place, (lat, lng)`, when it's actually a list of those; there are `too many values` in that list `to unpack` into just the two (`place` and `(lat, lng)`), since there are actually 10. You could do something like

```
for place, (lat, lng) in g.geocode(a, exactly_one=False):
     print place, lat, lng
```

or do some other kind of list manipulation or whatever.

Answer (score 1):

`g.geocode()` returns a **list** of nested tuples `(place, (lat, lng))`. Just use list comprehension to flatten it in a **list** of single level tuples `(place, lat, lng)` for
easier manipulation like this:

```
data = ((place, lat, lng) for place, (lat, lng) in g.geocode(a, exactly_one=False))
print "\n".join("%s: %.5f, %.5f" % t for t in data)
```